# Java command line arguments through shell script

Tags: java, shell, unix, command-line, command-line-arguments

when I try to command in command line it executes fine

```
$: /application/jre/bin/java -classpath /application/common/lib/apps.jar: ./updater.jar com.application.updatermain mobile
```

This executes perfectly fine and returns me the results whereas when I try putting this in a file called `run.sh`

If I create a `run.sh` as

```
/application/jre/bin/java -classpath /application/common/lib/apps.jar: ./updater.jar com.application.updatermain $@
```

and try to run it

```
./run.sh mobile
```

it acts weird

My java code:

```
if (args.length == 1) {
    if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("mobile") ) {
        updateDB = true;
    } else {
        System.out.println(" 1 :Usage: ./run.sh [mobile] "+ args[0]);
        return;
    }
}
```

It gives me the output

```
1 :Usage: ./run.sh [mobile] mobile
```

Am I missing anything here.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Don't put `$@` in quotes.

Comment: Tried that didn't work :(

Comment: What do you gent when you print `args` (not only `args[0]`)?

Comment: Why there is as space before  "./updater.jar"? Should not it be part of the classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that some space add to argument.
you must `trim` the `arg[0]` :

```
  if (args.length == 1) {
     if (args[0].trim().equalsIgnoreCase("mobile") ) {
        updateDB = true;
     }
  else {
        System.out.println(" 1 :Usage: ./run.sh [mobile] "+ args[0]);
        return;
     }
  }
```

Comment: I am not getting any space, when I try to print it.

Comment: try this : System.out.println(" 1 :Usage: ./run.sh [mobile] #"+ args[0] + "#");

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space before  `"./updater.jar";` the script `"run.sh"` should contain:

```
/application/jre/bin/java -classpath /application/common/lib/apps.jar:./updater.jar com.application.updatermain $@
```